# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3) using Django

Tags: python, django

using Django check_password() got this error, in database i have stored using hashed password using make_password() imported required statements

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password,check_password
```

line giving error is

```
password = check_password(pas, fetchRes[0][3])
```

here is my code

```
def signin(request):
    res=""
    login_failed = False
    conn = sql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="agroxpert")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if request.method=="POST":
        met=request.POST
        aid=met['aid']
        pas=met['pas']
        inp=(aid,)
        cur.execute('''SELECT * from admin where AID=%s''',inp)
        fetchRes = cur.fetchall()
        password = check_password(pas, fetchRes[0][3])
        if password and len(fetchRes) == 1:
            request.session['FID']=aid
            login_failed = False
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('administration/')
        else:
            login_failed = True

            res = "Unable to Signin Password or Admin Id entered is incorrect"
            print(res)
    return render(request,'admin.html',{"res":res,"failed":login_failed})
```

Here is the error:

Internal Server Error: /signin
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\project\AgroXpert\login\views.py", line 91, in signin
password = check_password(pas, fetchRes[0][3])
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py", line 49, in check_password
must_update = hasher_changed or preferred.must_update(encoded)
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py", line 272, in must_update
algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Comment: please provide full traceback, or atleast the line number in which error is happening

Comment: `password = check_password(pas, fetchRes[0][3])`